# MongoDB Storing Large Keywords Table Query Performance

Tags: java, mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

I need to store a collection containing a large number of keyword objects example:

```
{ key: "tokyo", someMeta: "meta.." }

db.keyword.createIndex({ key: 1 }, { unique: 1 })
```

I will use it as a look-up dictionary, so it will be called extremely often.

As I understand it, this look up takes O(log n) complexity, so it's not as fast a looking up from a HashSet O(1).

Should I use perform look up using this indexed query, or should I instead query all objects from the collection, put it in a HashSet, and look up from that hash set subsequently?

Lets assume i have more than a million objects in that collection..

Answer (score 0):

I've benchmarked the same task about a year ago. The bottleneck is not B-tree (because some DBMSes allowed to create HASH-indexes), but jdbc-driver, network stack and so on.

Java's native Hashmap is 300-500++ times faster then Oracle/MySQL(even with in-memory tables), Postgres, Mongo - all located on the same server.

Also Hashmap takes twice **LESS** memory comparing to in-memory Mysql.

For map with 3 millions of records it was about 1GB of RAM for Hashmap.

Also, surprisingly, Mongo wasn't fastest of all. I've expected Mongo to lead among DBMSes

The winner for RAM consumption was PostgreSQL and MySQL with 350MB both, Mongo 650MB.

Comment: do you know if there will be any issue reading > a million objects from the collection and storing it into a static hashset? This hashset needs to be updated too as required manually.

Comment: The only issue is lack of synchronization. If you have several readers and sometimes update this hashmap, they can get different results. For JavaEE this can be solved through making singleton EJB and accessing it through JNDI.

Comment: For single-threaded tasks hashmaps are great. I often use them for internal caching. Then processing 1TB of data, HashMap of 40GB is not uncommon. Of course you should modify startup options, for example java -Xmx50g will push limit of java heap to 50 Gigabytes

Comment: I see, since this hashset will only use for read purposes, i guess it will be fine as well in multi-threaded environment. I don't think i will have GBs of keywords :)